# Generating a cross zero pulse wave

Tags: arduino, power-supply, voltage, pwm, zero-crossing

For a project I need a zero crossing wave like this

[image]

Its generated by an inductive coil of a distributor of a car engine where that signal triggers a CDI (capacity discharge ignition) when it falls from positive to under -0.3v.

My target is to reproduce or at least mime such a zero crossing wave with a PWM wave using an Arduino Nano in a car environment.

In the circuit below I tried this by using a 2N3904 NPN transistor where the -5 volt are provided by an ICL 7660.

[image]

But with this circuit it results only in a +1v/-1v PWM (screenshot below) and not in a +5v/-5v PWM … actually a +2.5v/-2.5v PWM would be sufficient.

[image]

**My question is: how can that circuit above be optimized to get at least a zero crossing +2.5/-2.5v PWM.**

Thanks a lot in advance and sorry for the first complicated question attempt.

Comment: You need to ask a question.

Comment: My question is, how the circuit above can be optimized, as that simple 3904 way as I used above shurely is a very poor way. Many thanks.

Comment: It's unclear in what direction optimization will be regarded as producing a better signal. Only you know that. You haven't really explained what the ideal signal is that you need and, you need to put this information in your question and not in comments. Do you mean a 2N3904 transistor? Is your lower graph an optimized or ideal signal? What makes it ideal if it is?

Comment: I'm having a hard time following what optimization is also please edit the question

Comment: Question edited and hope its more clear, thanks a very lot and sorry.

Comment: If you just switch your transistor in your current circuit for a PNP and change your bottom resistor to be 10x your top one, it will do what you want

Comment: Thanks BeB00, I'll try your suggestion as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the 5 V PWM signal to the + - 5 V PWM, this is an option:
[image: pwm5]

It would be a little more complicated to make a + -3V PWM signal:
[image: pwm3]

Comment: thanks a lot, thats what I needed. Only one more question.
I think then 0-5v PWM signal here on the very left should not be the one directly provided by the digital ouput pin of the Arduino ... but better from a (7805) 5v supply where this will be switched by also a 2N3906 driven by the Arduinos digital pin PWM?

Comment: The 0-5 V PWM can come directly from Arduino. Nothing is required between the transistor emitter and the CPU pin.